# Problem with Django not finding a module 'learning_logs'

Tags: python, python-3.x, django

I've been trying to fix this Django issue. I've just started this project and I'm fairly new to this language so I don't know where exactly is the issue.

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\user\Desktop\Projects Python\Django\manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:\Users\user\Desktop\Projects Python\Django\manage.py", line 18, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 401, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 377, in execute
    django.setup()
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\__init__.py", line 24, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\apps\registry.py", line 91, in populate
    app_config = AppConfig.create(entry)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\apps\config.py", line 90, in create
    module = import_module(entry)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1030, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 984, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'learning_logs'
```

**models.py:**

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.

class Topic(models.Model):
    text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    date_added = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.text
```

**settings.py:**

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'learning_logs',
]
```

Any help I would really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

In settings.py, the Installed apps should be written as 'app_name.apps.appconfig'.
The 'appconfig' is the same as the class name in app/apps.py

In you case it might be something like learning_logs.apps.LearningLogsConfig

Comment: Same issue still. I've tried what you have told me about putting the class name in the apps.py section but it still doesn't seem to work well